# Getting child objects from parent

Tags: soql

I have a Salesforce Parent child relationship. I need to get parent and child records from a Heroku app. Following is the SOQL. However partner stub does not have a way to get child records? Anyone knows how to do this?

```
SELECT id, (select id,cxsrec__Job_requirements_text__c,cxsrec__Job_description_text__c from cxsrec__Job_profile_translations__r)  FROM cxsrec__cxsFunction__c where id = 'XXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

I debugged and found a way to do this. Find the sample code.

```
    public void test(){

    try {
        PartnerConnection connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
        QueryResult qResult = null;
        String soqlQuery = "SELECT id, (select id,cxsrec__Job_requirements_text__c,cxsrec__Job_description_text__c from cxsrec__Job_profile_translations__r)  FROM cxsrec__cxsFunction__c where id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'";      
        qResult = connection.query(soqlQuery);          
        SObject [] sObjects = qResult.getRecords();
        for (SObject sObj:sObjects) {
            XmlObject obj =  sObj.getChild("cxsrec__Job_profile_translations__r");
            Iterator<XmlObject>iChild = obj.getChildren();
            while (iChild.hasNext()) {
                Object obj1 = iChild.next();
                if (obj1 instanceof SObject) {
                    SObject objs = (SObject)obj1;
                    System.out.println(objs.getId());
                    System.out.println(objs.getField("cxsrec__Job_requirements_text__c"));
                    System.out.println(objs.getField("cxsrec__Job_description_text__c"));
                }
            }               


        }

    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```